# How to collapse vectors using paste to create function with both * and +

Tags: r, regression, interaction

I have two vectors

```
s.null <- c("a1","a2","a3")
s.full <- c("a1","a2","a3","b","c","d")
```

I am comparing a null model to a full model, the null where I'm creating my null model like so:

```
null.model <- lm(as.formula(paste(colnames(data)[i], "~",                   
                              paste(s.null, collapse = "*"), 
                              sep = ""
)),
data=data)
```

So that my model looks like

```
some_data_value ~ a1 * a2 *a3
```

ie the interaction between terms a1,a2,and a3 is accounted for in the null model.

I would like to do the same thing in the full model but have the covariates b, c, and d also present:

```
some_data_value ~ a1 * a2 *a3 + b +c + d
```

but I am unsure of how to use paste to accomplish this. If anyone could offer a solution as to how I could use paste to accomplish this I would be very grateful!

Comment: For the second cases `paste('some_data_value ~ ', paste(s.full[1:3], collapse=" * "), "+", paste(s.full[4:6], collapse = " + "))`

Comment: Thanks! The first suggestion worked, I adapted it to make it iterate over values in 'data' like the null model. I'm posting that here in case anyone is later interested:

   full.model <- lm(as.formula(paste(colnames(data)[i],"~", 
                paste(s.full[1:3], collapse=" * "),"+", 
                paste(s.full[4:6], collapse = " + "),
                sep=""
                )), 
             data=data)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

We can use either `paste`

```
paste('some_data_value ~ ', paste(s.full[1:3], collapse=" * "),
            "+", paste(s.full[4:6], collapse = " + "))
```

Or in a slightly different way to construct the formula

```
paste('some_data_value ~ ', paste(matrix(s.full, ncol =2),
       rep(c(' * ', ' + ', ''), c(2, 3, 1)), collapse=''))
```

or `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
glue::glue('some_data_value ~ {str_c(s.full[1:3], collapse = " * ")} + {str_c(s.full[4:6], collapse= " + ")}')
#some_data_value ~ a1 * a2 * a3 + b + c + d
```

---

Or may be use `reformulate` with `update`

```
update(reformulate(setdiff(s.full, s.null), 'some_data_value'), paste(". ~ . *", s.null))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use null model terms to construct full model formula

```
formula(paste('some_data_value ~', paste(s.null, collapse = " * "), '+', 
        paste(setdiff(s.full, s.null), collapse = " + ")))

#some_data_value ~ a1 * a2 * a3 + b + c + d
```